# what is [-1, 1] in this ruby code?

Tags: ruby

I am looking at an example of code and confused.

```
def self.type(input) 
  input.strip!
  return 'question' if input[-1,1] == '?'  
end
```

So, input[-1] makes sense, it is checking if the last character is a question mark. What does the `1` do? Also, all the example tests pass without the `1`.

Comment: You knew what the method was, why not just [look up the args in the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D)?

Comment: Can you explain what *exactly* in the documentation is unclear to you? That way, the Ruby developers can improve the documentation for future readers, but only if you actually tell them *where*, *how*, and *why* the existing documentation doesn't help you answer this question.

Comment: I didn't check the documentation.

Comment: @coreyward: BTW: I recently found out that you can delete the version number from the URI, and it will always redirect to the most recent version. That could be "dangerous" if you want to refer to *specific* content or wording, but if all you want to do is to link "the docs", then that might be a good idea, since it will automatically pick up improvements in the doc or new arguments.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Dope!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`input[-1,1]` means reading 1 character from the last character. It gives the same result as `input[-1]` because you are reading just 1 character from the last character.

Look at some examples to understand more:

```
❯ irb
2.3.0 :001 > input = 'lenin'
 => "lenin"
2.3.0 :002 > input[-1]
 => "n"
2.3.0 :003 > input[-1,1]
 => "n"
2.3.0 :004 > input[-2]
 => "i"
2.3.0 :005 > input[-2, 1]
 => "i"
2.3.0 :006 > input[-2, 2]
 => "in"
2.3.0 :007 > input[-2, 3]
 => "in"
```